# Horizontal Scroll & different size of images in gridview of android like Windows8 App Tiles

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I have tried  `android:scrollbars="horizontal"`  property too but it is not working when I increase number of columns from 4 to 10 it does not show scrollbar it disarrange the images they overlap each other.
is there anyway to slides images in `Horizontal` instead of `vertical` and also how I can use multiple size of images in grid like this

[image]

when I set `column number 4` then it looks like that
[image]

when I increase column numbers up to `column number 10`

[image]

**activity_main.xml code:**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"


/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
   // protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   // }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        //gridview.setNumColumns(10);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
         {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**ImageAdapter.java class**

```
package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));            
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

**What I want:**

1) I want to slides images in horizontal
2) images should be different sizes like Windows8 MetroStyle like above first image

Answer (score 0):

Gridview is not meant to use for different size of cells. You have to customize the tiles layout for that looks. For that you can use either tableLayout or linearLayout.